# Where to post question about Windows problem?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm having a crazy problem on my laptop. I searched the web but couldn't find anything.

So I was wondering on which Stack Exchange site I should ask about my problem ("Console Window Host has stopped working").

Comment: post it on http://superuser.com

Comment: Thanks alot, by the description superuser didnt seem to fit but looking at the site I guess your right.

Comment: have you read the faq of superuser ?

Comment: Time to 1) reinstall windows and 2) stop running as admin

Answer (score 6):

From [Super User](http://superuser.com)'s [faq](https://superuser.com/faq)

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - **computer software**

so not really sure what made you think it's not on topic for Super User.

(I'm a Super User Moderator)

Comment: **computer enthusiasts and power users** to me this doesnt sound like the site for the average joe with a computer problem.

Comment: @m1sk [su]'s been running for about 3 years now, and I think this is probably the first time I'm hearing about this. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Sathya, add a Diamond the bracket :)

Comment: @Sathya - Maybe you need to add "Super User is for computer enthusiasts, power users, and the average joe...". Although that may attract stuff you don't want, so don't listen to me ;)

Comment: @m1sk All sites are aimed at experts, but that doesn't mean we don't allow Average Joe to ask questions. Also, the vast majority of our users come on our site through Google and I don't expect Joe to start using expert jargon when asking his question. If you see a question of your level, wouldn't you think your question would be allowed as well?

Comment: @m1sk - What all sites need is expert **answers** to questions from anybody. This is something we've had to make explicit in the Programmers FAQ.

Comment: Who says a noob can't be enthusiastic?  I was enthused as hell when I got my first computer.  Didn't know jack squattery about it or what to do with the damned thing.  If you are having computer problems and you don't know jack and you don't want to learn, you are typically going to ask a lousy question.  If you are a total noob but enthusiastic, you are more likely to care about your question and the answers you get, as you want to learn.